# Help finding source ונטמתם

Tags: sources-mekorot, grammar-dikduk, commentaries

There seems to be this teaching (gemarah) in the Talmud (Yoma 39) on Vayikra/Leviticus 11:43 regards the phrase ונטמתם. Because this is written without the expected alef it could be read as v’nitamtem instead of v’nitmeitem.

Oke so here’s my question, different sources I found point to a Rabbi Yismael and translate his explanation of the word as ‘dull, stupid’. Yet others refer to [Rabbi Bachye](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/chrysler/archives/shmini69.htm) 
and translate the word as ‘blocked’.

I’m looking for the source where I can find Rabbi Bachye his statement. And I’m looking for the root of this word which could mean dull, stupid and/or blocked.

P.s.
Putting it into a translator like doitinhebrew.com gets the following outcome: ‘And you were dead’, could anyone explain me if there is a connection to death somehow?

Comment: "_Putting it into a translator like doitinhebrew.com gets the following outcome: ‘And you were dead’_ ...". Interesting. When I put "ונטמתם’" into doitinhebrew.com's translator (or into Google translate, for that matter), I get: "And you were sealed". Though they may have come a long way, I wouldn't put too much stock in automatic translators (on the web). Also, bare in mind that though the spelling "ונטמתם" suggests "becoming מטומטם/dull-witted", I don't think it's actually a word (at least not in modern Hebrew), so automatic translators might try to give the next best thing they can find.

Comment: Are you looking for [the commentary of Rabbeinu Bechaye (ben Asher) on Vayikra 11:43](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.11.43?lang=bi&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Vayikra.11.43&lang2=bi)?

Comment: It may be better not to consult doitinhebrew.com

Comment: @TamirEvan Yes, I think he is - you have an answer!

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you, can’t believe I didn’t find it myself,  must have missed it somehow